# A way to count by group and keep result in same table in R

Tags: r, sum, group

I am looking for a function to count by a character variable ID and keep the count in the table, so that I can use it as a criteria for keeping or deleting.

I found this example of sum (https://statisticsglobe.com/count-unique-values-by-group-in-r), but it collapses the table and instead I want to keep the table and mutate a variable into it. The mutated variable "Count" should count by ID group like this simplified example:

| id | x | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01x | 234 | 2 |
| 01x | 23 | 2 |
| 02 | 23 | 2 |
| 02 | sf | 2 |
| 03d | s | 3 |
| 03d | sreg | 3 |
| 03d | see | 3 |
| 04 | rrd | 1 |

Kind regards,
Jacob

I found this example but it doesn't allow sum by character variable:
https://sparkbyexamples.com/r-programming/group-by-sum-in-r/

```
agg_tbl <- d %>% group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(count=sum(id),
            .groups = 'drop')
```

Comment: are you looking for something like this? `mutate(d, count = length(id), .by = id)`

Comment: Or `mutate(df, count = n(), .by = 'id')`

Comment: This is the difference between mutate (adds/updates a new column) and summarise (collapses data per group).

Comment: Thank you very much, Mark and Allan Cameron - both solutions work fine!